# Error in Swift: property 'self.circle1' not initialized at super.init call?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to programming and am trying to write a tic-tac-toe app in Swift, and this error is preventing me from running the app: property 'self.circle1' not initialized at super.init call.

The app is not finished yet but I don't see where the error is in the existing code. Please explain any suggestions thoroughly as once again I am a BEGINNER. Thanks! 
My code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Initializing all imgs as variables:

    @IBOutlet strong var circle1: UIImageView
    @IBOutlet strong var circle2: UIImageView
    @IBOutlet strong var circle3: UIImageView
    @IBOutlet strong var circle4: UIImageView
    @IBOutlet strong var circle5: UIImageView
    @IBOutlet strong var circle6: UIImageView
    @IBOutlet strong var circle7: UIImageView
    @IBOutlet strong var circle8: UIImageView
    @IBOutlet strong var circle9: UIImageView

    @IBOutlet strong var circleBtn1: UIButton
    @IBOutlet strong var circleBtn2: UIButton
    @IBOutlet strong var circleBtn3: UIButton
    @IBOutlet strong var circleBtn4: UIButton
    @IBOutlet strong var circleBtn5: UIButton
    @IBOutlet strong var circleBtn6: UIButton
    @IBOutlet strong var circleBtn7: UIButton
    @IBOutlet strong var circleBtn8: UIButton
    @IBOutlet strong var circleBtn9: UIButton

    @IBOutlet strong var resetBtn: UIButton
    @IBOutlet strong var ResultsLabel: UILabel

    //Creating variables:

    var plays = Dictionary<Int,Int>()
    var done = false
    var aiDeciding = false

    //Function that says what to do if a UIButton is clicked:

    @IBAction func UIbuttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
        ResultsLabel.hidden = true
        if !plays[sender.tag] && !aiDeciding && !done {
        setImgforCircle(sender.tag, player:1)

        }

    //Executing these functions:

        checkforWin()
        aiTurn()

    }

    //Function that sets an X or O in the proper circle depending on player:

    func setImgforCircle(spot:Int, player:Int) {
        var playerMark = player == 1 ? "x" : "o"
        plays[spot] = player
        switch spot {
        case 1:
            circle1.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 2:
            circle2.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 3:
            circle3.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 4:
            circle4.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 5:
            circle5.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 6:
            circle6.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 7:
            circle7.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 8:
            circle8.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        case 9:
            circle9.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

        default:
            circle2.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
        }

    }

    //Function that sees if certain paths of circles have the same mark

    func checkforWin() {
    var whoWon = ["Lost":0, "Won":1]
        for (key,value) in whoWon {
            if ((plays[1] == value && plays[2] == value && plays[3] == value) || //across top row
            (plays[4] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[6] == value) || //across middle row
            (plays[7] == value && plays[8] == value && plays[9] == value) || //across bottom row
            (plays[1] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[7] == value) || //down left column
            (plays[2] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[8] == value) || //down middle column
            (plays[3] == value && plays[6] == value && plays[9] == value) || //down right column
            (plays[1] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[9] == value) || //diagonal going right
            (plays[7] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[3] == value)) { //diagonal going left

                ResultsLabel.hidden = false
                ResultsLabel.text = "You \(key)!"
            }

        }

    }
    func aiTurn() {

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Why do you have the `strong` keyword in there? If you remove `strong`, your errors will go away. Or, if you're going to make them `strong`, you have to initialize them in your `init` method.

Comment: rule 1: the `IBOutlet`s are always `weak`.

Comment: Even when I remove "strong" I still have the error.

Comment: And are all of the IBOutlet's hooked up in IB?

Comment: @Rob the strong keyword is there because Xcode puts it there automatically when you ctrl connect a storyboard object to the UIViewController. user3724215 if you delete the strong keyword it should remove the init warning

Comment: ... but if you need to maintain a strong connection (keep the strong keyword?), then you should be able to write for example @IBOutlet strong var circle1: UIImageView? - which is best practice at the moment I'm not sure

Answer (score 3):

Just add a question mark or an exclamation mark at the end of the declaration:

```
@IBOutlet strong var circle1: UIImageView?
```

With Swift, every variable has to be initialized before calling super.init. In this case, the variable won't be initialized until the Storyboard or nib is loaded, and that will be after your class init method is called.

The type of your circle1 variable; in addition to being a UIImageView; will be an Optional, so it needs to indicate that in its declaration. Consequently, you'll need to unwrap the variable to access it's value with either the question mark or the exclamation mark.

```
let prax = circle1?.image
```

or

```
if circle1 {   // now you're sure the object exists
   let prax = circle1!.image
}
```

*( Xcode6 Beta-4 seems to have resolved this, and automatically gives "click to fix" error buttons in the code editor. )*

Answer (score 2):

You're lacking the initialization of your optional variables declared in your class, which must be done before calling `super.init()`

```
init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
  self.circle1 = UIImageView()
  super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

Comment: Optional variables do not need to be declared in init. Plus his variables are defines as IBOutlets, I imagine he wants them connect in a Nib.

Comment: It is also asking for initialization in required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

Comment: @AbdulYasin that is "normal". Unless you are decoding/encoding objects, you can leave that as a fatalError. However, I do suggest you take the time to implement it, which you should refer to NSCoding guidelines if you have not done before: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html

Answer (score 2):

The `@IBOutlet` in in this line

```
@IBOutlet strong var circle1: UIImageView
```

hints that the `UIImageView` circle1 (and all the other `UIImageViews`) are placed in a storyboard or xib file. The storyboard needs to make a connection from the elements defined there to the objects in your ViewController code (the circle1 var).

To make this connection open the storyboard, open the assistant editor (you have three buttons on the top right of xcode, the second one is the assistant editor). You should now get two editors next to each other. In one have the storyboard open, in the other your ViewController file. Now Ctrl-Drag with the mouse from your UIImageView in the storyboard to the circle1 variable in the ViewController. Repeat for every element and the error should be gone.

Comment: I did that in the beginning and I just did it again and I'm still having the error.

Answer (score 0):

UIButtonClicked function should look like this for updated versions of swift...

```
    @IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
            ticTacLabel.hidden = true
            if plays[sender.tag] == nil && !aiDeciding && !done {
                setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
            }
```

Hope this helps!